# Does order of CSP directives matter?

Tags: content-security-policy

The `default-src` has a special behavior as you can imagine it as a "fallback" or "alias" for other directives (such as `script-src`, `style-src` etc.).

At https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#example-fae89c48 it is also mentioned that there is a certain "overwrite" behavior, if `default-src` and one of its counterparts (e.g. `script-src`) are mentioned in the same CSP header.

But what about order of the directives?

As an example: Is

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src-elem https://example.com
```

semantically the same as

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src-elem https://example.com; default-src 'self'
```

? Does now `script-src-elem: 'self'` apply or `script-src-elem: https://example.com`? I.e. is the string parsed from left to right or do we have "precedence by CSP directive name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#framework-directives states that a policy is an **ordered set** of directives. This could suggest that order matters.
However, the standard provides the statement that

> For example: if the effective directive name is `worker-src` (meaning that we are currently checking a worker request), a `default-src` directive should **not** execute if a worker-src or script-src directive **exists**.

at https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#should-directive-execute (emphasis provided by the author of this answer). This can be read that `default-src` shall be ignored completely (independent of its position in a `serialized-policy`), if a more specific CSP directive is provided.

A brief test also shows that contemporary browsers behave like this. Let's have an html file with the following content:

```html
<img src="https://example.com/test.webp">
<br/>
<img src="test.webp">
```

This file is streamed by a webserver, which will add the following header to the html file's request:

- Variant A: `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src https://example.com`
- Variant B: `Content-Security-Policy: img-src https://example.com; default-src 'self'`

The client (in my case a Firefox 121.0 (64-bit)) shows the same behavior for both variants: The first image (hosted on origin `https://example.com`) is shown, whilst the loading of the second (hosted on `'self'`) is reported by the network tracer to be prohibited by CSP.

### tl&dr;

Although CSP's specification defines a policy to be an ordered list, the order of `default-src` and `img-src` do not matter. It is assumed that this is the same for [all other directive names for which `default-src` is defined as fallback](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#directive-fallback-list).

Hence the evaluation is based on "precedence by CSP directive name".